# Am I creating a leak here?

Tags: c#, json, idisposable, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json

I am using the new JsonSerializer from NETCore 3.0's System.Text.Json namespace to deserialize Json documents like this:

```
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Response>(json, options);
```

Response is defined as:

```
public class Response
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public JsonElement Bar { get; set; }
}
```

The fact that [JsonDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=netcore-3.0) implements IDisposable makes me wonder if by keeping a reference to an element (`Bar`) that can be contained in a JsonDocument, will create memory leaks?

Be advised that in general I avoid storing data as kind of "variant" type like this. Unfortunately the structure of the `Bar` property value is unknown at compile time.

My suspicion stems from System.Text.Json advertised strength's of lazy evaluation and I'm not sure if that involves deferred I/O.

Comment: i think that the IDisposable refers to the object that does the deserialization.  Not the result.

Comment: @JohnB Well, keep in mind that one of the advertised strength's of System.Text.Json is lazy evaluation. I'm not sure if that involves deferred I/O.

Comment: best practice for using this objects that implement `IDisposable` is to have a `using` block.  once the code execution leaves the block the dispose is called.

Comment: You aren't using JsonDocument here, only JsonElement, which is just a struct and doesnt implement IDisposable. The two things are independent I think

Comment: @ADyson I know, but the element could very well maintain a back-reference to the actual document used for deserialization, IF the deserializer actually uses a JsonDocument instead of working on with a Utf8JsonReader directly.

Comment: If you wanted to be certain that wasn't going to be an issue then you could make use of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.clone?view=netcore-3.0#System_Text_Json_JsonElement_Clone

Comment: Maybe see if the source of [`JsonDocument`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Text.Json/System/Text/Json/Document/JsonDocument.cs,b49b0ad124503b72) or the source of [`JsonSerializer`](https://source.dot.net/#q=JsonSerializer) are of help to you.

Comment: There's no leak.  `JsonSerializer` has a built-in converter [`JsonConverter<JsonElement>`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Converters/JsonValueConverterJsonElement.cs) which calls [`JsonElement.Clone()`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Document/JsonElement.cs#L1776).  This method copies the `JsonElement` out of its host `JsonDocument` as a standalone object allowing the document to be disposed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From a brief investigation of sources (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Document/JsonDocument.cs) it seems that JsonDocument Dispose returns "rented" bytes to shared array pool and does some general cleanup.
Some instances of JsonDocument are marked as not disposable and in this case Dispose will not do anything.
You can check this flag for your instance using reflection - if your instance doesn't have internal IsDisposable flag set to true there is no need to worry, because Dispose will not do anything anyway.

I think in normal scenario, JsonDocument parser should clean after itself and there should be no rented bytes left or internal data after parser is done.

It's always safe to not rely on specific implementation though as it may change and store only references to elements needed. You should probably remap JSON elements to your model, I think that's the whole purpose of JSON deserialization

Quick test:

```
        var parentField = result.Bar.GetType().GetMember("_parent", MemberTypes.Field, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)[0] as FieldInfo;
        var parentDocument = parentField.GetValue(result.Bar);

        var isDisposableProperty = parentDocument.GetType().GetProperty("IsDisposable", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic) as PropertyInfo;
        Console.WriteLine(isDisposableProperty.GetValue(parentDocument)); // false
```

Proves that the instance of JsonDocument held by JsonElement is not disposable.

Comment: Keepinh data in a general purpose structure like this, is generally something I'd avoid at all cost. Problem with the Bar property is that the structure of the value is unknown at compile time.

Comment: Excellent investigation. +1

Comment: "I think in normal scenario, JsonDocument parser should clean after itself and there should be no rented bytes left" That's true from the serializer (if you can see it, it's not using the ArrayPool), but not when you call JsonDocument.Parse directly (explained more in a different answer).

Answer (score 8):

When you call `JsonDocument.Parse` it uses pooled arrays to avoid garbage collection pauses in high throughput.

When you Dispose that document it puts the arrays back in the pool, if you lose the reference and it gets garbage collected... it's the same as if it hadn't been disposable at all (*slightly* worse, since some other aspect of the runtime may suddenly be where things pause and the GC kicks in because the pool has fewer arrays now).

`JsonElement` has a `Clone` method (but isn't `ICloneable`) which returns a copy of the (relevant) data using a `JsonDocument` instance that doesn't use pooled arrays.

JsonSerializer, when returning `JsonElement` values, always calls `Clone()` and then disposes the original `JsonDocument`.  So when you use `JsonSerializer` and get a `JsonElement` (directly, or through overflow properties) it's the same as if `JsonDocument` was built without an `ArrayPool` optimization... so everything's fine.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this "if you lose the reference and it gets garbage collected... it's the same as if it hadn't been disposable at all" in the answer? Or maybe try to explain it also in a different way, since this is somewhat unclear to me.

Comment: @AndreiBozantan I'll try: "Pretend the type wasn't declared as IDisposable, what would happen? When the object is no longer rooted it gets garbage collected.  That's the same that happens here -- the difference is that if you do properly dispose it, some of the memory goes back to a memory pool instead of the garbage collector, which has some performance benefits. Either way, there's no leak."

Comment: @bartonjs This answer used to be correct, but [this change](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/commit/b673eea8acacb1cdcfd5e59b7bbcab036eafa3ce#diff-f9364c308d2e80d13ec576a561a4e2a6dff8e3c720bb8e22d9468b52ff5b9eaa) in Oct 2020 has removed the `JsonElement.Clone()` call in `JsonElementConverter`, so `JsonElement`s returned by `JsonSerializer` is actually disposable now. Not sure if this has real-world implications though (e.g. memory leak or performance impact).

Comment: @scharnyw Interestingly, I got asked about the array-pool usage of JsonDocument/JsonElement yesterday (perhaps related...).  Anyways, that change made the JsonSerializer use `JsonElement.ParseValue`, which (::giant handwave::) is functionally equivalent to `using (jsonDocument) { return jsonDocument.RootElement.Clone(); }` (it's actually more efficient since it never rents in the first place).

Comment: @bartonjs Thanks a lot for the confirmation. I think it would be nicer if the `JsonDocument` wrapped by `JsonElement` returned from `JsonElement.ParseValue()` has `IsDisposable` set to false though (as you mentioned it doesn’t hold rented memory). Would reduce some confusion such as those raised in this question.